# Looking for title of book about a man with nanomachines in blood

Tags: story-identification, nanotechnology

Back in the 90's I read a book and I have not been able to remember an author or a title, numerous searches have also found nothing.

I can only remember random details about the book. It is about a man who crash lands on a planet. He has nano machines of some kind in his blood that make him stronger, can heal a broken bone and administer morphine when he is injured, increase the length of his life, and they turn is skin a metallic color, I believe gold but maybe it was silver. They are powered by a power unit installed in the base of his spine.

The planet he crash(?) lands on plays a game involving tiles to work out their political issues instead of fighting wars, at the end of the book when they use the tiles to quickly advance technology to develop weapons.

At some point in the book/series the man gets imprisoned and has nothing to do but play the game, when he gets out of prison he has become a genius at it.

I would really love to reread this book, please help!

Comment: Although this has been accepted already as "The Player of Games", there are quite a few similarities to "The Last Hawk" by Catherine Asaro, published 1997.

Comment: I've now ordered this book to see if is the one I'm looking for. The synopsis sounds closer to what I remember. I'll update after I've read it.

Comment: @RossPresser "The Last Hawk" is definitely the correct book! Please post it as an answer so I can mark it properly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description is also pretty close to [The Last Hawk](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/672961.The_Last_Hawk) by Catherine Asaro, published 1997. Kelric, the protagonist, is a golden-skinned (not just tan or yellowish; they have metallic tints in their skin in his race) Jagernaut, a warrior with nanotech biological enhancements. He's also a telepath. On the planet he crash-lands, there is a matriarchal society, and the woman he marries "owns" him to a great extent. The game played is Quis, with crystalline "dice" of various shapes that are arranged in patterns on the table.

[image: Cover image]

Comment: This is part of Asaro's "Skolian" series, of which many are available in ebook form. Some of those are [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/s-4-catherine-asaro.aspx).

Comment: I bought it off Audible since I'm currently traveling. I've listened to the first few chapters and this is absolutely the book I was looking for. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Joe -- glad to help!

Answer (score -2):

Also applies to Greg Bear's"Blood Music"

Comment: Aside from the nano-machines, "Blood Music" bears no relation whatsoever to the story described above; http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791153/9781625791153___2.htm